# help with radians

Tags: geometry

Ok, I am attempting to mark positions on the inside of sphere, (360° Panorama). I am having trouble wrapping my head around the math. I am storing a longitude(between 0 and 2π) and a latitude(between -(π/2) and +(π/2)) for the location of a point.

The problem is i have no control over the the origin point (0,0), it is set to the center of the source image(vert) and join point at the 2 far ends (where the 2 edges of the image meet to complete the sphere). If a new image replaces an old one, the seem may be in a different place, so I figured I would store an offset value for north.

If I know the coordinates of north, how do I work out positions relative to this point? I would like to store the offset value so if a new image is loaded with a new "north" point, the points will still match up (at least as good as how close the 2 north points are together.)

Keep in mind that values outside the ranges specified above would be invalid.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCq4L.jpg)

Comment: If you’re using a 3D object, especially a sphere, it might be worth checking out [spherical coordinates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)

Comment: i don't think i need to store all 3 coordinates as the size of the sphere never changes, i also have no control over the coordinate system. i can either store the lat/lng or an x/y texture coordinate. even though the math would be simpler with the x/y coordinates, there would be more chance of error's due to calculating the size of the image incorrectly, where as the lat/lng are always in a specific range (image could be 500x250 or anything up to 50,000x25,000)

Comment: A panorama is typically a band around the sphere, centered around a great circle. If you’re doing anything except taking a series of images around the equator of your sphere, things can get weird quickly. It’s hard to advise you because it is not sufficiently clear what images you actually need to deal with.

Comment: @DavidK the panoramas are generally taken with a 360 camera (2 180 deg lenses) in some cases using a mobile phone and stitching the photo's together. i am using https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org to display them. the images are applied to the inside of a sphere as a texture, you can then "zoom" and "pan" around to view the area.

Comment: Maybe if you showed a couple of examples of panoramas showing where the "north" point is on each photo, it would be clearer. I initially thought you meant that "north" was directly overhead (at the pole of the sphere your photo is pasted inside), but if it's actually on the horizon and just shifted left or right in different photos (which are all taken with the camera aligned with the horizon) then that's a different matter.

Comment: @DavidK "but if it's actually on the horizon and just shifted left or right in different photos (which are all taken with the camera aligned with the horizon) then that's a different matter" this. ultimately i am trying to achieve something similar to google street view, where you link up multiple 360 panorama's on a map to "walk through" a location. by storing the coordinates of the panorama and the "orientation (north point of image)" i am hoping to be able to "link" the panoramas together. (i can work out the bearing between 2 panoramas and link them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to find a pure mathematical solution, but have come up with a mix of logic at math that should do the job.

If someone else comes up with a better solution and posts it, I will change that to the selected answer. But in the meantime what i ended up with follows:

To Calculate the position(offset) to store:

```
    calcOffset = function(point, north){
        var markerLatLng = {lat: '', lng: ''};
        markerLatLng.lat = point.lat-north.lat;
        markerLatLng.lng = point.lng-north.lng;
        return markerLatLng;
    }
```

To take the stored position(offset) and place it according to 0,0

```
    useOffset = function(point, north){
        var pi = Math.PI;
        var markerLatLng = {lat: '', lng: ''};
        if((point.lat + north.lat) > (pi / 2)){
            markerLatLng.lat = (point.lat + north.lat)-pi;
        } else if((point.lat + north.lat) < (-1 * (pi / 2))){
            markerLatLng.lat = (point.lat + north.lat) + pi;
        } else {
            markerLatLng.lat = point.lat + north.lat;
        }

        if((point.lng + north.lng) > (pi * 2)){
            markerLatLng.lng = (point.lng + north.lng) - (pi * 2);
        } else if((point.lng + north.lng) < 0){
            markerLatLng.lng = (point.lng + north.lng) + (pi * 2);
        } else {
            markerLatLng.lng = point.lng + north.lng;
        }
        return markerLatLng;
    }
```

Sorry for the javascript, happens to be what i have to write this in.